# Hardr disk space deacreasing by 1gig everyday

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, meteor

I have installed meteor, nodejs and MongoDB on ubuntu 14.04. Everyday i find my hard disk space decreasing by almost 1 gig. What may cause that. Initially i had 16 gig and it was full, then i have to increase it by 24gig to make it 40gig. now in 3 days after the upgrade that hard disk is now 21 gig. The server is an instance EC2 on Amazon

Comment: Isn't it just your application that is writing data to the database?

Comment: No, i have another partition where I installed the mongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

A easy way to find out where all your space is being use is:

```
  sudo du -h -d 1 <location>
```

Example:

```
  sudo df -h -d 1 /
```

Output:

```
 759M   /usr
 15M    /home
 6.9M   /run
 6.4M   /bin
 16K    /lost+found
 4.0K   /mnt
 1.5G   /
```

This will get you output of your HDD space consumptio
n from your root directory,
just follow the output and run command again by changing the directory  see which directory has taken up all the space.

**UPDATE:**

As you said docker is taking up space on your server see [this](https://meta.discourse.org/t/low-on-disk-space-cleaning-up-old-docker-containers/15792/38)

Comment: Thank you very much AJS. The folder which is growing is var/lib/ folder

Comment: sure no problem mark the question answed and close the question if your query is solved

Comment: Hi AJS, I found that my /var/lib/docker is the folder that is growing daily. How can I handle this case. My apologies for the delayed response.

Comment: updated my answer with possible link to your solution.

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-31-5-57:~$ sudo du -ch -d 1 /var/lib/docker
9.9G /var/lib/docker/containers
8.0K /var/lib/docker/tmp
2.9M /var/lib/docker/image
60K /var/lib/docker/volumes
4.0K /var/lib/docker/trust
1.4G /var/lib/docker/aufs
60K /var/lib/docker/network
12G /var/lib/docker
12G total

ubuntu@ip-172-31-5-57:~$ docker ps -s
CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES SIZE
6029a2b4c013 mongo "/entrypoint.sh mongo" 10 weeks ago Up 2 weeks 127.0.0.1:27017->27017/tcp mongodb 0 B (virtual 309.8 MB) My fear is that I may delete information. Wat is the best command to run

Comment: I want to preserve my mongoDB data

Comment: why dont you take a mongo dump before you do take any action.[mongo dump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)

Comment: My challenge is that have little knowledge with mongodb, i wouldnt know how to restore or backup it

Comment: you can use above mongo dump link for backup and this [restore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) to restore the data its quite simple go through the information

Comment: i am not a container expert may be you should post another question and see if someone can help you regarding this

Comment: from the link i added to my answer about docker ie https://meta.discourse.org/t/low-on-disk-space-cleaning-up-old-docker-containers/15792/44 it seem to be safe after reading comments there

Comment: see [this](https://meta.discourse.org/t/low-on-disk-space-cleaning-up-old-docker-containers/15792/45) comment

Comment: The challenge is that this solution only works with discourse only